# export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"eval "$(rbenv init -)" not valid in this context: export path

Tags: ruby, terminal

I was trying to install ruby on my machine. I had to add this -

```
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

The error I get every time I open my terminal

`/Users/akash/.zshrc:export:23: not valid in this context: export PATH`

Rest of my .zshrc -

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/clear/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/clear/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/clear/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/akash/Desktop/Projects/cheaplops/clear/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'; fi

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/akash/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/akash/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/akash/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/akash/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"eval "$(rbenv init -)"

export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Answer (score 3):

First check do you have openssl installed, the second part is for rbenv but first one is setting openssl so your software can use that specific version.

```
brew info openssl@1.1
```

See what it show will give you details or not installed. If not installed you have to install it. Then run following command to see you can see directory from brew for openssl.

```
brew --prefix openssl@1.1
```

If path is visible that mean all good. Now check do you have rbenv install? that is software to be installed before doing this.

```
brew install rbenv
```

Now I found one error in your whole line, as that line is actually creating export entry, but there is nothing to separate command eval from export, try following command.

```
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

If you notice before eval I added `;` so one process complete and next can run. You are basically setting options --with-open... in a environment variable, and then you are running command of rbenv. You can use following lines to install ruby I took reference from [rbenv discussion](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1353)

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl"; rbenv install 2.3.8
```